# Bootstrap carousel controls not changing active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get the Twitter Bootstrap carousel to work. The slides change how they should after the default timeout, but somehow the indicators don't change the active class and therefore my carousel doesn't change its slides.

I tried to program the click on the carousel manually, but this wasn't sufficient, because the slides then only changed on click and not by default without click after a period.

I also checked whether the "active" class on the carousel items changes on click as well as after the default timeout period. AS described above the "active" class doens't change on click on the controls, but after the timeout it does.

Here you can find the code of my carousel:

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100 carousel-img carousel-img-1" src="resources/img/1x1.png" alt="First slide">
            <div class="hero-text-box">
                <blockquote style="color: white">
                    <div class="center-logo">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="resources/img/logo-viereck.jpg" alt="Logo">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <q style="font-size: 150%">Besuche ich gern, wenn ich in der Nähe bin. Super Angebote zum fairen Preis. Die Theken und
                        Auslagen sind stets sauber. Das Personal ist auch sehr freundlich und auf Augenhöhe.</q>
                    <br>&minus;
                    <cite>Jörg B.</cite>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100 carousel-img carousel-img-2" src="resources/img/1x1.png" alt="Second slide">
            <div class="hero-text-box">
                <blockquote style="color: white">
                    <div class="center-logo pb-3">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="resources/img/logo-viereck.jpg" alt="Logo">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <q style="font-size: 150%">Wie immer Super! Qualität, Service und Preis sind top. Einmal Bernys Cook immer Bernys Cook.
                        Selbst für weitgereiste und große Fahrzeuge ist immer ein Parkplatz vorhanden.</q>
                    <br>&minus;
                    <cite>Simon H.</cite>
                </blockquote>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100 carousel-img carousel-img-3" src="resources/img/1x1.png" alt="Third slide">
            <div class="hero-text-box">
                <blockquote style="color: white">
                    <div class="center-logo pb-3">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="resources/img/logo-viereck.jpg" alt="Logo">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <q style="font-size: 150%">Wie immer sehr schnell und äusserst lecker! Weiter so!! Sehr zu empfehlen! An alle Trucker:
                        Hier lohnt es sich einzukehren! Super Essen mit Allem drum und dran!</q>
                    <br>&minus;
                    <cite>Frank W.</cite>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:-

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">

    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" alt="Chicago">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="New York">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```